# Values are not initializing under try block?

Tags: java, arrays

trying to make program rotation of array, it was giving an Exception by user misinput so I use try block but now, under try block it is not initializing values....
Can some one tell the reason or solution for this....

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayRotation ar = new ArrayRotation();
        System.out.println("Enter T : ");
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        
        sc.nextLine();
        while(t!=0){            
            System.out.println("\nEnter N D : ");
            String s = sc.nextLine();
            s.trim();
            String st[] = s.split(" ");
            int n,d;
            try{
                n = Integer.parseInt(st[0]);
                d = Integer.parseInt(st[1]);
            }catch(Exception e){                System.out.println("Exception"+e.getMessage());         }
            System.out.println("Enter Element : ");
            s=sc.nextLine();
            st = s.split(" ");
            
            ar.rotateArray(st,n,d);
            t--;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Well, when the user enters a bad input, like "A B", what do you think the values of `n` and `d` will be?

Comment: Initialize n and d = some integer where you have declared them

Comment: According to the image you posted, both compilation errors are occurring on line 34 of file `ArrayRotation.java`. Which line is line 34? Could it be this one? `ar.rotateArray(st,n,d);`

Comment: Everyone, please stop telling Chetan to initialize `n` and `d` to zero.  That will make the program compile, but it won’t make the program work.  Quietly treating invalid input as if it’s valid is not good programming.

Answer (score 1):

If you need valid input and you did not get valid input, the thing to do is to **try again** to get valid input, after telling the user the input was invalid.  Don't just proceed with the invalid data. You therefore need an inner loop:

```
    while (t!=0) {    
        boolean validInput = false;
        while (!validInput) {        
            System.out.println("\nEnter N D : ");
            String s = sc.nextLine().trim();
            String[] st = s.split(" ");
            int n,d;
            try {
                n = Integer.parseInt(st[0]);
                d = Integer.parseInt(st[1]);
                validInput = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
            }
        }
        … process n and d as before …
    }
```

For my taste the loop to get the valid input would be better off being a subroutine in its own right - for clarity.

Comment: This is not the solution! This will still generate the **compile** error.

Comment: Shutting the compiler up is the trivial part of the problem. The important par of this answer is that you don't just ignore bad input and proceed with the computation.  (FWIW, there's a scope error in my answer too).

Answer (score 0):

Variable in local scope should be initialized , that is what error , so do initialize the variables n and d to some integer value say as below

```
int n = 0 ,d = 0;
            try{
                n = Integer.parseInt(st[0]);
                d = Integer.parseInt(st[1]);
            }
```

Comment: I would like to know the reason for a downvote . SImply giving downvote will not help improve!

Comment: Probably because it does not solve the actual problem. It's just a local band-aid. Now the program is going to ignore invalid input and execute with one or both values set to zero.  A correct solution would be to recover from illegal input by (1) saying clearly the input was wrong, (2) re-requesting input.

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi is right. The OP (through the provided image) is asking why the **Compilation Error** is occurring and this is exactly why. It has absolutely nothing to do with whether or not valid input was provided. The initialization of the variables `n` and `d` is moved out of scope because of the **try/catch** and therefore the call to **rotateArray()** (where it is located) will generate the initialization error since after all, the rule is that local variables must be initialized before they can be used. Move the call into the **try/catch** and problem solved, no compile error.

Comment: Thank you @DevilsHnd . yes that is what my concern was , if OP says this is the error he or she is facing , we should answer regarding that . and yes if some issue comes up later on , let there be another question asked to community.

Answer (score 0):

When a method throws an exception, that method never returns.

This means that if `n = Integer.parseInt(st[0]);` throws an exception, it does not return a value, which means `n` will not be assigned a value (since there is no return value to assign to it).

You are ignoring the exception and trying to continue as if nothing went wrong.  But something *did* go wrong—`n` was never assigned a value.  So the compiler tells you that it is not safe to use `n` in any subsequent code.

To solve this, you first must decide what to do if the user provides invalid input.  You can’t just ignore the exception.  If the input doesn’t represent two integers, *you don’t have any values to work with.*  You can’t continue in any meaningful way.

The best course of action is to remove your `try` and `catch`.  This will cause the program to terminate if Integer.parseInt fails, which is almost certainly what you want (unless your assignment requires you to do something different).  Remember that it is not possible to continue in any meaningful way without values assigned to `n` and `d`.

In other words, change this:

```
int n,d;
try{
    n = Integer.parseInt(st[0]);
    d = Integer.parseInt(st[1]);
}catch(Exception e){                System.out.println("Exception"+e.getMessage());         }
```

to this:

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(st[0]);
int d = Integer.parseInt(st[1]);
```

As a side note, this line does nothing:

```
s.trim();
```

…because Strings cannot be changed.  `s.trim()` returns a *new String* which you must capture in a variable.  You probably want to do this:

```
s = s.trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image is quite misleading and really doesn't point to the actual problem, it only points to what **you** perceive to be the problem. Your mistake was placing the initialization of variables `n` and `d` into a **try** block which takes your call to the **rotateArray()** method out of scope for that initialization of those variables.

The bigger problem is... What in the world are you rotating? Where is the Array to rotate? Is it actually a String Array or is it suppose to be an Integer Array? Please don't tell me it's the **st[]** String Array (which is what you're trying to do) because according to your code that array is used to establish the array size (**n**) portion to work with and the number of elements (**d**) the User wants to rotate by. No rocket science to rotate an Array with only two elements. Give the **rotateArray()** method an array to actually rotate.

Let's provide an Integer Array and a way to do this without a **try/catch** mechaism:

```
// The Array to carry out rotations on.
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

String ls = System.lineSeparator();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayRotation ar = new ArrayRotation();
int t = 0;
String value = "";
while (value.equals("")) {
    System.out.print("Enter Number of times to Rotate Array: --> ");
    value = sc.nextLine().trim();
    /* Make sure a String representation of a Integer value is supplied.
       The regular Expression "\\d+" in the String#matches() method
       ensures the a numerical integer string is supplied.       */
    if (!value.matches("\\d+" || value.length() > 9) {
        /* Will handle situations where nothing is supplied, alpha 
           characters might be supplied, or the supplied numerical 
           value is outrageously large.    */
        System.out.println("Invalid integer numerical value supplied!" + ls);
        value = "";
    }
}
t = Integer.parseInt(value);
    
while (t != 0) {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Enter the Size (portion) of the Array to consider and the" + ls
                   + "number of elements to rotate (separated with a space): --> ");
    String s = sc.nextLine().trim();
    // Quit if anything starting with the letter "Q" 
    // (like "q" or "quit") is supplied.
    if (s.substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
        System.out.println("\"Quit\" Supplied!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    String st[] = s.split(" ");
    /* Make sure two values were supplied and that 
       they are both numerical integer strings.   */
    if (st.length != 2 || !st[0].matches("\\d+") || !st[1].matches("\\d+")) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input! Try again and make sure 'both' "
                         + "values are numerical Integers.");
        continue;
    }
    // Declare and initialize the n and d variables.
    int n = Integer.parseInt(st[0]);
    int d = Integer.parseInt(st[1]);

    /* If the number of elements to rotate is greater 
       than the portion of array to rotate in.     */
    if (d >= n) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input! The size of the Array portion to rotate" + ls
                         + "must be greater than the number of elements to rotate.");
    } 
    /* If the supplied Array size to deal with is 
       out of bounds of the Array itself.     */
    else if (n < 1 || n > array.length) {
        System.out.println("You have supplied an invalid Array Size! (" + n
                      + ") Size must be between 1 and " + array.length + "!"
                      + ls);
    }
    /* If the supplied number of elements to rotate 
       is less than 1 or greater than the total number
       of elements - 1.            */
    else if (d < 1 || d > (array.length - 1)) {
        System.out.println("You have supplied an invalid number of elements to rotate! (" + d
                + ") Value must be between 1 and " + (array.length - 1) + "!" + ls);
    }
    // All is good - Do the rotation.
    else {
        ar.rotateArray(array, n, d); // Rotate the Array
        
        // Display the current rotation...
        System.out.println("Current Rotation: --> " + Arrays.toString(array));
        t--; 
    }
}
// Done
```

The error you outline in your image is a general **compilation** error and is relatively generic for all data types. This error occurs when you are trying to **use** a **local** variable without first initializing it. You won't get this error if you use a uninitialized class or instance variable because they are initialized with their default value (for example: Reference types are initialized with null and integer types are initialized with zero), but if you try to use an uninitialized **local** variable in Java, you will get this error. This is because Java has the rule to initialize the **local** variable before accessing or using them and this is checked at **compile time**. If the compiler believes that a **local** variable might not have been initialized *before the next statement which is going to use it*, you will receive this error. You of course will not get this error if you just declare the **local** variable but don't use it but then, why declare it in the first place.

Everyone is stating to initialize the local variables `n` and `d` because in reality, in order to successfully **compile** your code that is exactly what needs to be done in order for the **rotateArray()** method (which uses these uninitialized variables) to function. Again in reality, you do initialize them however your code does it within a **try{}** block which alters scope and the compiler is smart enough to know that if the initialization fails within the **try{}** block then the **catch{}** block could let that failure be ignored. In fact, if you were to place the call to the **rotateArray()** method within that **try{}** block then you would not get this compile time error since the call is within the scope of of where the variables `n` and `d` are actually initialized. You know, a decent IDE (line Eclipse, NetBeans, InteliJ, etc) ***should*** catch this error for you long before you try to compile.

According to your code, the actual intent of the **try/catch** blocks would be to handle the case of invalid input whereas a non-numerical integer value was supplied by the User. In this case it would be up to your **catch{}** block to handle that particular situation which **should** be to inform the User of the invalid input and then *continue to re-prompt for proper input*. At compile time the compiler really doesn't care about this mechanism since this would be a **Runtime** Error unless of course it is syntax related.

Nothing wrong with **try/catch**, I just like to avoid them if I can.